# Href not working in Chrome, does work in IE

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

I have this website which I'm attempting to work on. I've obtained a template, which I'm editing the HTML to customize. There exists a section on the page that has three icons with a "More" button beneath them. I've set the button to link to another webpage, but it only works on IE -- not Chrome. Further, the icons themselves are supposed to change as you hover, which again they do in IE but not in chrome.

I have this code:

```
.intro3 {
  text-align: center;
  color: $(intro3.color);
}

.intro3 .row {
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 120px 0 120px 50px;
}

.images_author {
  font-size: 6em;
}

.images_author span {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 160px;
  height: 160px;
  line-height: 160px;
  color: $(intro3.circle.right);
  border-width: 40px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 100%;
  border-top-color: $(intro3.circle.left);
  border-right-color: $(intro3.circle.right);
  border-bottom-color: $(intro3.circle.right);
  border-left-color: $(intro3.circle.left);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -moz-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -ms-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -o-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
  transition: all 0.5s ease-out;
}

.authsx:hover .images_author span {
  color: $(background.color.all);
  border-style: double;
  border-top-color: $(intro3.circle.left);
  border-right-color: $(intro3.circle.left);
  border-bottom-color: $(intro3.circle.right);
  border-left-color: $(intro3.circle.right);
}

.intro3 .fourcol div.padd_25 {
  padding: 25px;
}

.intro3 .fourcol div strong {
  font: normal normal 22px  PT Serif,serif;
  line-height: 1.8em;
}

.intro3 .fourcol p a.more_aut {
  font-size: 12px;
  margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 30px;
  background: transparent;
  color: $(intro3.color);
  font-weight: bold;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: 2px solid $(intro3.color);
  border-radius: 6px;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
```

Which sets up for the (where the action is executed):

```
  <div class='intro3'>
<div class='row'>
  <h2 class='title_s authors'> Explore </h2>
    <div class='fourcol authsx'>      
      <div class='images_author coll_1'>
       <span class='icon fa fa-linkedin'/>
      </div>
      <div class='padd_25'>
        <strong>LinkedIn Profile</strong>
      <p>Connect via LinkedIn. See my skills, experience, and qualifications.</p>
        <p><a class='more_aut' href='http://www.linkedin.com/in/amandabayless'><span>More</span></a></p>
      </div>
     </div>

    <div class='fourcol authsx'>
     <div class='images_author coll_2'>
       <span class='icon fa fa-user'/>
      </div>
      <div class='padd_25'>
        <strong>About Me</strong>
      <p>Learn more about me. </p>
        <p><a class='more_aut'>More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class='fourcol last authsx'>
     <div class='images_author coll_3'>
                 <span class='icon fa fa-paperclip'/>
      </div>
      <div class='padd_25'>
        <strong>Samples of Work</strong>
      <p>See a small sample of my work. </p>
        <p><a class='more_aut'>More</a></p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I only have very rudimentary skills here, and much internet sleuthing could not show me why there was a difference in the browser. For reference, [This is the website.](http://www.amandabayless.com/) Could anyone offer advice? I don't know where to go from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Inside `#page-content` there is an element with class `intro3` which has a pseudo element `:after`. The pseudo element overlays your links. Give it a lower `z-index` or remove it if you do not need it.

Comment: That's it! Thank you! Could you perhaps quickly explain to a beginner like me the :after - z-index relation? I don't understand what it means (only that it worked).

Comment: I am glad it worked! Here is an [explanation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/09/the-z-index-css-property-a-comprehensive-look/#what-is-it) of z-index. Pseudolements interact with other boxes as if they were real elements inserted just inside their associated element. Here you can find more: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/generate.html#before-after-content